# Classes in c# with constructor

Tags: c#

What does the end of the header mean?

```
MobilePhone(string phoneNumber, string name) : this(phoneNumber)
{
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: What header? Which part exactly are you referring to and how is it unclear?

Comment: this(phoneNumber) calls another constructor that only acceps a phonenumber.

Answer (score 1):

`: this(phoneNumber)` invokes another constructor overload that only accepts a phone number (or at least a `string`):

```
MobilePhone(string phoneNumber, string name) : this(phoneNumber)
{
    this.name = name;
}

//this one is invoked using 'this(phoneNumber)' above
MobilePhone(string phoneNumber)
{
    this.phoneNumber = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to the `: this(phoneNumber)`.

This is basically a second constructor call. It is called constructor chaining.

You basically have two constructors and one calls the second one for its contents.

```
//Constructor A gets called and calls constructor B
MobilePhone(string number, string name) : this(number) 
{
    this.name = name;
}

//This would be constructor B
MobilePhone(string number)
{
    this.number = number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this(phoneNumber)
```

means 'before you call the below code, call the **other** `MobilePhone` constructor (which takes a single `string` parameter), passing in `phoneNumber` as the parameter to it'.